# Semantic way to create a selection list

Tags: html

My application needs a sidebar that shows a list of options and highlights the selected one. I do not want a drop-down as that requires the user to click it first before all the options can be seen.

This is the sort thing I have in mind (example from w3schools website):[image]

I opened up the Firefox DevTools and saw they used `<a>` elements, however I don't believe this to be the correct approach for my app as it as a SPA and as such does not have separate pages.

What would be the most semantic way to write the markup?

Comment: instead of using external links, you can use #id and scroll-behavior (maybe nested in one of the semantic tags like <nav> or <aside>) as I see in MDN Mozilla documentation if you think that w3school is not professional

Comment: *it as a SPA and as such does not have separate pages* — Plenty of SPAs make use of the history API and (for example) React Router (idealy coupled with SSR provided by something like Next.js) to provide bookmarkable URLs for different parts of the app. It's an effective, accessible, search engine friendly approach. We don't really know what context you are wanting this list to appear in though.

Comment: @Quentin I would like to avoid multiple pages if possible because this is intended to be an Electron app and so gains no benefit from having separate URLs, as for the context, this list would be a category selector and I would alter what data is shown in another pane to contain items of the selected category

Comment: An idea I've come up with is maybe to use and `<input type="radio">` nested within a `<label>` for each item and apply a style of `appearance: none` to the radio buttons so as to remove the visible checkbox and then just change the `background-color` of the label according to the `selected` psuedo-class of the input to indicate selected status?

Comment: `<a>` is definitely the most appropriate. If you’re really against using different URLs for pages for some reason, you can give them `href="javascript:;"`.